# Example of transferfrom() smart contracts with fictional wallet addresses

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts

Can anyone please create transferfrom() smart contract for me with fictional wallet address I'm trying to find out where exactly the address are positioned, it's only 4 to 5 lines of code I would really appreciate the help.

Trying to find out exactly where the wallet addresses are positioned